# Why do I have random return values in my type in Fortran, with -O2?

Tags: gcc, fortran, compiler-optimization

in my little code example I have random values for the variable testvar%bed when I compile with -O2 optimization.

```
gfortran -O2 test.F90
```

**edit** *to make the problem more clear:*

So the problem is, that I print `testvar%bed`, and it shows random junk, that changes on every run (unprintable characters, like `�����`). It should be printing `bed`.

This only happens on some systems. On

- debian gcc 4.9.1 -- okay
- osx gcc 4.9.1 -- okay
- ubuntu gcc 4.9.1 -- random values
- arch gcc 4.9.2 -- random values

This happens if the function is called two times in the code. If I comment out the second call, everything is okai again.
I can also "kind of fix" this if I put an arbitrary print statement at the end of the function.

**edit** *in reply to @tkoenig*

The problem does not occur with only `-O1` or without any optimizations. It does occur with `-O1 -fgcse` but not with only `-fgcse`. Only using `-ffrontend-optimize` alone does not rise the error.

What am I missing?

```
program testbug
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: STRLEN = 256
  type :: ncVarnames_t
    ! variables names for the different ice models
    character (len=STRLEN) :: surf
    character (len=STRLEN) :: x, y
    character (len=STRLEN) :: bed
    character (len=STRLEN) :: thick
  end type ncVarnames_t

  type (ncVarnames_t) :: testvar
  type (ncVarnames_t) :: testvar2

  print *, "hello"

  testvar = get_ncVarnames ("test")
  testvar2 = get_ncVarnames ("test")

  print *, trim(testvar%surf)
  print *, trim(testvar%bed)
  print *, trim(testvar%bed)
  print *, trim(testvar%surf)

  contains
  type (ncVarnames_t) function get_ncVarnames (model) result (v)
    character(len=*), intent(in) :: model
    ! type (ncVarnames_t)          :: v

    select case (model)
      case ("test")
        ! test model
        v%x = 'x'
        v%y = 'y'
        v%surf = 'surf'
        v%bed = 'bed'
       case ("pism")
         ! pism data
         v%x = 'x'
         v%y = 'y'
         v%surf = 'usurf'
         v%bed = 'topg'
      case default
        print *, "unknown model, please use one of [test pism sico]"
        stop
    end select
  end function get_ncVarnames
end program testbug
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? What do you expect it to do and what does it **not** do?

Comment: I print the variable `testvar%bed` and it shows random stuff `(��������)`, where it should print 'bed'

Comment: Could you update your question with the relevant information rather than adding it in the comments. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update accordingly. I'm saying that because it will increase your chances of getting a useful answer. It really will. Please follow the guidelines in  [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Okai, I did that, you are right. I hope this is more clear now.

Comment: Can confirm that valgrind reports uninitialized access with 4.9.0 and not with 4.8.3 on OpenSUSE 13.2. Ideally one should test the trunk, but I don't have it here.

Comment: I would suggest looking in the gfortran bugzilla for a report of a similar issue and if it is not there file a new one. I can't find any undefined behaviour in your example.

Comment: I see no issues with the code, and observe no issues with 4.9.2 or current trunk on Fedora 21 x64.

Comment: Does `-O2` make a difference?  If it does, what happens if you put in `-ffrontend-optimize` without one of the `-O` options?

Comment: The problem does not occur with only `-O1` or without any optimizations. It does occur with `-O1 -fgcse` but not with only `-fgcse`. Only using `-ffrontend-optimize` alone does not rise the error. (I added this to the question)

Comment: I can reproduce with gcc 4.9.2 on gentoo.  Bad output with `-O2` or `-O1 -fgcse` but not with `-O1 -ffrontend-optimize`.  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a gfortran/gcc bug, which may need some special circumstances to trigger (which is why not everybody appears to be able to reproduce it).

I have also reproduced this and submitted [PR 65504](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65504). This is a regression against 4.8, so it should receive special attention. Fixes should also be backported to 4.9.

Workaround (as analzyed in the PR): Use -fno-dse.

Comment: Thank you for filing that bug report! I'm curious how this resolves and until then I'll use `-fno-gcse`.

Comment: If you are **really** curious, you could get yourself a bugzilla account and get on the CC list of that bug :-)